# App, plugin, or something that allows for taking small notes in/on Google Calendar

Tags: note-taking, google-calendar

I'm looking for a way to take some notes in Google Calendar.  There doesn't seem to be a direct solution.  I already use reminders and events but I'm looking for a way that I can drop a note on a specific day, not tied to any particular event, for example to track my daily expenses or that my snakes have been weighed or fed.

Requirements:

- Integrates and/or syncs with Google Calendar.  I'd like to continue using Google Calendar because 3rd party apps can't use Reminders, but if I can take notes and sync my regular events I'd be happy.
- Takes notes, no reminders or times, just select a day and type a note.
- Web and Android support.

Any such thing exist?